# Windows 7 ad-hoc internet sharing - How to share with static IPs?

Tags: windows-7, network-shares, dhcp, ad-hoc-network

I'm trying to share internet via ad-hoc connecting two Windows 7 computers.
The ad-hoc network only works with static IPs, but when I try to share the internet, Windows pops a message saying that the other computers needs to be configured to retrieve the IP automatically in order to work.
So, this is some kind of catch-22 I think...ad-hoc only works with static, internet sharing only works with DHCP.
I've Googled and couldn't find a solution.
The funny thing is, sometimes the internet sharing works, it seems to be a random phenomena, if I connect the PCs (using static), then enable the connection sharing, one in 5 (approx.) tries the thing works, if I set the 'client' PC to automatic IP and reconnect the ad-hoc network.
I found that most people just give up on ad-hoc and simply buy a proper router, I don't have this alternative, so please, help me make it work :D.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you have to use the DNS 192.168.0.2 on the machine that's connecting to the one that's sharing the connection.